# I have a simple python dict why is a generator reference printed instead of the dict

Tags: python, generator

A simple dict is created:

```
 procinfos = {"f1": f1, "f2": f2, "f3shell" : (wrap_for_process, q, f3shell, "input arg1", "input arg2")}
```

Then I want to print its contents:

```
 print (procinfo for procinfo in procinfos)

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f46dccc0dc0>
```

Why does python just tell me this is a generator?  How can I simply print the contents.  From what I have read about generators, they are intended not to consume the dict/list. But this is already a fully concretized collection - makes no sense (to me at least..) to not simply print it.   This is a v common use case, would appreciate a succint way to get a basic print of these collections. thanks.

Update: I want this in an single line / inline, not multi lines. thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a single line solution only? It's not better because it's less lines.

Comment: If you want to know "How can I simply print the contents" of a dictionary… have you tried `print procinfos`? That's about as simple as can be.

Comment: @Regebro: Depends on the use cases: for mine less lines is better. my use cases include: printing multiple things (including this one ) in one statement and b) saving screen real estate. You don't have to consider it useful for your use cases/all use cases.. Requesting on one line is a worthwhile requirement for my use cases.

Comment: @javadba: That explanation just pushes things farther up. Why do you need to print multiple things in one statement, instead of in separate statements? Meanwhile, it's perfectly reasonable for Lennart to suggest that if you want to write Python code that other Python developers read (or, in this case, that other Python developers help you write), you should follow Pythonic style.

Comment: You only actually mention one use case, saving screen real estate, and it's not a good one. Yes, it's worth voting down, it's code golf and makes for worse code. Code golf and obfuscating is good for fun, but bad for actual code used in real life.

Comment: I have worked in groups that had rigid code structure requirements, in one of them your comments would have applied. But you err by over generalizing to apply your comments of code structure to all cases.

Comment: @javadba: Python has an idiomatic style that nearly everyone loosely follows. If you're writing code for nobody but you to read, you can ignore that, but if you're writing code that you expect other Python developers to read, or to help you with, you can't. Code golf is not pythonic, period.

Comment: There are perfectly valid answers provided below that have positive votes and are on one line, It was a fair stipulation.

Comment: To all "stop trying to get it into one line".  Well python has plenty of places we _only get one line_.  I'm not a newbie at python over six years later and retain my position on this. Printing a collection (list/dict/set) needs to fit compactly and  in one line.  More generally  I find many co-workers that have double digit years experience in python agree with me to reject overreaching adherence to PEP/ "pythonic" principles (which are simplistic) and its general philosophies as counter productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use brackets instead:

```
print [procinfo for procinfo in procinfos]
```

Comment: I think that's going to be the solution - am newish to python and had neglected that in my last foray. thanks. I'll come back in a moment and accept.

Comment: This does the same as print procinfos.keys(), but using more memory and slower. ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: In 2.x, keys() builds the same list as this listcomp, so it won't save any memory, and will probably save very little time.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just figured he wanted something simple, but eventually beyond keys.

Comment: @abarnert: Maybe not memory (too hard to check) but doing the list comprehension over the keys is much slower. A quick timeit check indicates that it takes about 5 times the time.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing a generator.

```
procinfo for procinfo in procinfos
```

Is a generator expression. It will only be evaluated when iterated over. You can do that, for example by passing it to a list constructor:

```
list(procinfo for procinfo in procinfos)
```

But you can get the same result with (note 1):

```
list(procinfos.keys())
```

Or in Python 2 just:

```
procinfos.keys()
```

So most likely, do do what you want you can do:

```
print procinfos.keys()
```

If you want to print them one on each line you can do this:

```
print '\n'.join(procinfos)
```

Note 1: Actually just `list(procinfos)` will work, just as with '\n'.join(procinfos) but *why* it will work is less obvious, but it's because iterating over a dictionary will iterate over it's keys. This is a bit more advanced Python, so don't worry about it right now. :-)

Comment: Actually you don't ever need `.keys()`, you can use `list(adict)` in its place.

Comment: Jochen: Yeah, you are right. I skipped it for clarity, I'll add it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you passed a generator expression to `print`. `print` attempts to convert non-string arguments to strings, but generators don't have a nice, human-readable definition for **str** or **repr** since they're not evaluated until they're used (by an iterator), so you get the `<generator object...>` result. You need:

```
for procinfo in procinfos:
    print(procinfo)
```

For an inline solution, it depends on the formatting you're looking for, but I'd go with something like this:

```
print('\n'.join(procinfos))
```

Of course, this (and your original code) **only prints the keys** from `procinfos`. If you want the key:value pairs, you can do something like this:

```
print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in procinfos.items()))
```

I'm assuming you want the newlines or some other formatting in there, of course, because if you just want to print the whole dictionary out on one line, `print procinfos` is all you need.

Comment: Updated my question to mention am looking for an inline/single-line solution. thanks.

Comment: You can just use `items` in Python 2 as well as 3. Even if performance were relevant here, at least in CPython and PyPy, `join` is just going to effectively make a list out of the iterator (so it can make two passes) anwyay.

Comment: @abarnert I forgot that `items` was around in Python 2; I just figured `iteritems` was replaced by `items` in Py3. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Yes, 2.x `iteritems` became 3.x `items`, and 2.x `items` went away (you have to write `list(foo.items())` instead). Anyway, if you don't care whether it's a list or an iterator, you can just write `items` and it's fine for both 2.x and 3.x; if you do care, obviously you have to use the right method.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, if you explicitly give `print` a generator expression, it will print a generator.

If you want it to print a list, you have to either (a) make a list out of it, or (b) pass it a list in the first place (e.g., by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression):

```
print list(procinfo for procinfo in procinfos)
print [procinfo for procinfo in procinfos]
```

---

As Lennart Regebro points out, if you just want to print the keys of a dict, you don't even need a genexp or listcomp, because the `keys` method returns a list (in Python 2) or an iterator you can pass to `list` (in Python 3):

```
print procinfos.keys()
```

Or, for that matter (both 2.x and 3.x):

```
print list(procinfos)
```

---

And if you want to "print the contents" of a dict, presumably meaning both keys and values… just print the dict:

```
print procinfos
```

---

However, the best way to solve this is to not rely on `print` doing any magic and hoping `__str__` uses some formatting that's good enough. Instead, decide how *you* want the output to be converted to a string, and do it. For example:

```
print ' '.join(procinfo for procinfo in procinfos)
```

But of course all of the above points still apply here:

```
print ' '.join(procinfo)
print ' '.join(procinfo.items())
# ...
```